# Script hangs after input to zenity

Tags: bash, shell-script

I am trying to utilize zenity in my simple `ffmpeg-cut-mp3` script, but it hangs after the input into zenity :/ What's the matter with this?

```
#! /bin/bash

start=$(zenity --entry --title="CutMp3" --text="Start time ? (hh:mm:ss.ms)") &

duration=$(zenity --entry --title="CutMp3" --text="Duration in seconds ?") &

gnome-terminal -x ffmpeg -ss "$start" -t "$duration" -i "$NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS" -acodec copy "$NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS" &&

zenity --notification --text "File cut !"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should **not** be backgrounding the first two variable assignment lines with the `&` as you go along. You are executing `gnome-terminal` before the `zenity` processes have retrieved a value because they were lauched, then backgrounded, and the script moved on.

Comment: Ooooh ... that's it .. thank you very much :)